# TransactionTooLargeException in UsbHost mode

Tags: android, exception

I'm using usb-serial-for-android library and I am getting some strange results. After 2.5 hours of continuous communicating with the serial port and reading and writing successfully, I get this exception:

```
exception in UsbManager.openDevice
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
at android.hardware.usb.IUsbManager$Stub$Proxy.openDevice(IUsbManager.java:339)
at android.hardware.usb.UsbManager.openDevice(UsbManager.java:255)
at com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.UsbSerialProber$1.probe(UsbSerialProber.java:63)
at com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.UsbSerialProber.probeSingleDevice(UsbSerialProber.java:174)
```

But when i force close my app and then restart it, everything is fine and my app can communicate with the port again.

It maybe useful to mention that before the exception , I get this exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/log.txt: open failed: EMFILE (Too many open files)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:58)
at org.example.myapp.util.L.log(L.java:32)
```

I use class `L` for logging purposes:

```
public class L {

    public  synchronized void log(String message){

        File logFile = new File("sdcard/log.txt");
           if (!logFile.exists())
           {
              try
              {
                 logFile.createNewFile();
              } 
              catch (IOException e)
              {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
           }
           try
           {
              //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
              BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
              buf.append(new Date(DateProvider.getInstance().getCurrentDateAsMillisecs()).toString()+": "+message);
              buf.newLine();
              buf.close();
           }
           catch (IOException e)
           {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
    }

}
```

It seems that some kind of buffer or cache is getting filled and prevents communicating with the device.

How can I get rid of the exception?

Update:

**Writing to log file never fails even though I'm getting the exception. It only affects communicating with usb device.**

Comment: On your update. The problem is caused by what I described. Please fix those.

Comment: Did you get a notification similar to "An application has been forced to close for an unauthorized attempt to access system in your device" (mine's a french translation). I got a similar error, despite giving permission to the activity to access the USB device. Do you access the USB from a separate service? Is it in a separate process (as mine is)? I haven't found a solution, and happens every time for me (on one device it is fine though)

Comment: No I don't get this notification. In fact, the application is not force closed. I access the USB from a separate service but I don't have permission problems.

Comment: Have you even tried what I suggested?

Comment: I resolved the issue by doing openDevice in the activity instead of the service. Another bit of information is that it only happened on build JDQ39.I9505XXUDMI1 of 4.2.2 on galaxy 4S. It did not happen on 4.2.2 build JDQ39.I9505XXUBMH1

Answer (score 1):

You are opening too many files.
Problems I have found: 
 - You never close logFile 
 - You open the file in the log function, a static File would be better and could be initialized in a log_init(); function. 
Or, make logFile an object variable and initialize it in the constructor. 

I think solving these will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use [getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29) to pass the directory path while creating file

Answer (score 1):

```
public class L {

    public static File logFile = new File("sdcard/log.txt");

    public  synchronized void log(String message){        

       ....
```

Everytime you call new File you request a file resource from the system.  As you keep doing it the system will complain that you opened too many files.  To avoid this, request the file only once.

Comment: Snippet-only answers are not useful. It seems you switched two lines. Please explain why that would fix the problem.